# What is causing these lichen patterns on a tree in Scotland?

Tags: botany, mycology

I recently saw these lichens growing on a tree in Scotland. What is causing the pattern of dark lines? Are these the boundaries between individual lichens? Or could it be something to do with the growth of the tree (which is of diameter around 15cm)?

I'm more familiar with lichens growing on rocks, where these spatial patterns can potentially be used to improve rock dating (see e.g. this [article](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0012820)). Presumably lichens growing on tree bark are younger, but are potentially affected by other factors that don't apply on rock e.g. changes in the bark as the tree grows.

[image]